# Network really slow with TL-WN951N wireless card

Tags: networking, wireless

I literally just installed ubuntu and it seems to be working great except the network is deadly slow.

I'm running a TL-WN951N wireless card which can download at about 600-700 KB/s in windows but in Ubuntu the max speed it seems to get is around 5KB/s. I guess I should note that my WAP is only wireless-G but like I said, I can get much better speeds in Windows.

I'm testing the speeds by downloading files from here: http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/test/

Anyone have any idea? I saw some people recommend downloading drivers and compiling them myself but I'm really really new to all of this so would appreciate someone babying me through it so I don't brick my computer!

Here are the results of `lspci -v`:

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Giga-byte Technology GA-EP45-DS5 Motherboard
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
    Memory at e9110000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at e9100000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at e9120000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

05:02.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5008 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Atheros Communications Inc. Device 3071
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 168, IRQ 18
    Memory at e9200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Comment: If you're able, can you post the results pertinent to your wireless card from `lspci -v` (run via a terminal window)?  This will help us know what drivers you currently are using.

Comment: @AvatarKava: no worries, done :)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/275230) where the rtl-818x wifi card shows very weak signal, and weak signal = slow wireless. I've [posted a FIX](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/275230/comments/7) at bugs.launchpad.net, so maybe it could help you. That bug-fix was for the driver RTL8180, but yours is RTL8111/8168B. So, it you want to give it a try, download and execute the script to fix your network card driver:

```
wget -c "https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/275230/+attachment/1801830/+files/rtl8185-weak_signal_fix.sh" -O /tmp/rtl818x-weak_signal_fix.sh    
sh /tmp/rtl818x-weak_signal_fix.sh
```

Comment: Warning: that scripts reboots the computer after it has completed. It is a better idea to ask the user for rebooting so (s)he has a change for saving files.